# unable to checkout files in git directory

Tags: git

I'm just starting to use git, and I'm having some files and folders that are being modified and unable to be reset or checked out. I have tried all the command but they're still stuck as unstaged changes!
here is my config file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
        autocrlf = false
        safecrlf = false
        eol = crlf
```

I have tried to checkout each file and reset hard, what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) somewhere in your repository files? if this file contains the path/filename of the file(s) you want to add, this will not succeed, because they are ignored.

Comment: no I don't have a .gitignore file. those files are showing in my git status results.